# Left merge not working in Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge two dataframes `df` and `df1`. The csv for each df is over 10gb and has millions of rows so my kernal keeps dying when I try to merge.

Can I use spark to enable multicore processing for this and how do I avoid the kernal errors? I have a common column in `df` and `df1` which I am trying to merge using `merged = pd.merge(df, df1, on='Number and postcode', how = 'left')`. The reason for using `left` merge is because `df` has a number of duplicates in one column. I want to preseve these and lookup to each instance where df and df1 match in the `number and postcode`.

Comment: Yes, that's what Spark is for. Personally, I would use `Dask`

Comment: How does that work? Something like this?
`import dask.dataframe as dd`
`df = dd.read_csv(r'xxxxx')`
`df1 = dd.read_csv(r'yyyy')`
`merged = pd.merge(df, df1, on='Number and postcode', how = 'left')`

Comment: I would read the [docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-joins.html) there are plenty of guides online that can help you